# usage of BorderLayout

Tags: java, user-interface

I am having a problem with BorderLayout, that was set to the green JPanel side. It does not display elements on the EAST in a row order. Do I have to combine this with GridBagLayout ? Could someone advice me how should I tackle this problem?

Basically the problem is of displaying objects inside green area below when I am using
Current layout:
[image]

My aim is to achieve this layout:
[image]

```
public class GUILayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        JButton jbO = new JButton("CSIS0396");
        JButton jbl = new JButton("Final");
        JButton jb2 = new JButton("2010");
        JButton jb3 = new JButton("Exam");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

        JButton object_btn = new JButton("Object");
        JButton oriented_btn = new JButton("Oriented");
        JButton programming_btn = new JButton("Programming");
        JButton and_btn = new JButton("and");
        JButton java_btn = new JButton("Java");

        BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout();

        panel.setLayout(layout);
        panel2.setLayout(layout);


        panel.add(BorderLayout.CENTER,object_btn);
        panel.add(BorderLayout.WEST,oriented_btn);
        panel.add(BorderLayout.WEST,programming_btn);
        panel.add(BorderLayout.WEST,and_btn);
        panel.add(BorderLayout.WEST,java_btn);

        panel2.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, jbO);
        panel2.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, jb2);
        panel2.add(BorderLayout.WEST, jbl);
        panel2.add(BorderLayout.EAST, jb3);

        panel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        panel2.setBackground(Color.RED);


        jf.getContentPane().add(panel);
        jf.getContentPane().add(panel2, BorderLayout.EAST);

        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setSize(400, 300);
        jf.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: don't use same border layout for both panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't share same layout for multiple component and use box layout for left panel to positioning buttons

---

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class GUILayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        JButton jbO = new JButton("CSIS0396");
        JButton jbl = new JButton("Final");
        JButton jb2 = new JButton("2010");
        JButton jb3 = new JButton("Exam");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

        JButton object_btn = new JButton("Object");
        JButton oriented_btn = new JButton("Oriented");
        JButton programming_btn = new JButton("Programming");
        JButton and_btn = new JButton("and");
        JButton java_btn = new JButton("Java");

        BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout();

        panel2.setLayout(layout);
        panel.setLayout( new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));


        panel.add(object_btn);
        panel.add(oriented_btn);
        panel.add(programming_btn);
        panel.add(and_btn);
        panel.add(java_btn);

        panel2.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, jbO);
        panel2.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, jb2);
        panel2.add(BorderLayout.WEST, jbl);
        panel2.add(BorderLayout.EAST, jb3);

        panel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        panel2.setBackground(Color.RED);

        jf.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        jf.getContentPane().add(panel ,BorderLayout.WEST);
        jf.getContentPane().add(panel2, BorderLayout.EAST);

        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setSize(400, 300);
        jf.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that you're having your panels share a layout.  You must use a new BorderLayout for each of them.

The second problem is that a BorderLayout can only have one component in each constraint position.  When you try to add multiple components to the WEST position, each one replaces the one that was previously in that position:

```
panel.add(BorderLayout.WEST,oriented_btn);

// Implicitly removes oriented_btn from panel
panel.add(BorderLayout.WEST,programming_btn);

// Implicitly removes programming_btn from panel
panel.add(BorderLayout.WEST,and_btn);

// Implicitly removes and_btn from panel
panel.add(BorderLayout.WEST,java_btn);
```

The solution is to put them in their own container, such as a Box or a JPanel with a GridLayout:

```
Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
// Or:
//JComponent box = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
box.add(oriented_btn);
box.add(programming_btn);
box.add(and_btn);
box.add(java_btn);

panel.add(BorderLayout.WEST, box);
```